# Change IIS Express to full functions IIS when debug in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

In ASP.NET Unleashed book (SAMS Publishing, http://www.informit.com/store/asp.net-4-unleashed-9780672331121 ISBN-10: 0-13-256581-1 )
have a snippet: File: ***SendMail.aspx***:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "localhost";
        client.Port = 25;
        client.Send("nate@somewhere", "nate@exclaimcomputing.com",
        "Beware!", "Watch out for zombies!");
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Send Mail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Email sent!
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***The book warning:*** 
"...sends the email by using the local SMTP Server. If your SMTP
Server is not enabled, you receive the error An Existing Connection Was Forcibly Closed
by the Remote Host. You can enable your local SMTP Server by opening Internet
Information Services, right-clicking Default SMTP Virtual Server, and selecting Start."

By using Visual Sutio 2012, include built-in IIS Express, I can not practice this code, because IIS Express don't support SMTP.

Please help me **change IIS Express to full function IIS** to practice below snippet.

Comment: Why not just send to your ISP/Mail provider's SMTP server?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your question fully. Email address in below snippet is sample... I try to send mail (or fake mail) using localhost.

Comment: Why use localhost? Did you want to set up a mail server? It's trivial to obtain your mail provider's SMTP and to use that instead. If not, install IIS and change your project settings to use IIS instead of the dev webserver.

Comment: Thank @spender, Please show me how to "change your project settings to use IIS instead of the dev webserver" step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So you installed IIS ***after*** .Net, so make sure that you've run [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx).

Now, right click your project, choose properties and follow [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178108%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

IIS Express is a version on Home/Family editions, not professional/Ultimate.
If you don't have a Windows Pro/Ultimate you can install your own SMTP server, there are plenty of free good ones on the Web.

But if you don't want to lost time to instal/configure an SMTP server for testing emails you can directly send emails from the .Net Framework.

Comment: I am using Window 8 Pro, Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I go to Add and Remove Program Control Panel, and Add IIS serive to Windows 8 operating system. But I cannot put file FirstPage.aspx to C:\inetpub\wwwroot for testing, because Visual Studio don't compile my aspx file.

Comment: @tranvana: .aspx files aren't compiled by VS. They're compiled on first load/change by the .net hosting environment (IIS).

Comment: I try to put FirstPage.aspx to C:\inetpub\wwwroot , then run: http://localhost/FirstPage.aspx, but error: "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map."

Comment: @tranvana: http://codesnob.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/installing-iis-after-net-4/ probably applies to you because you installed IIS ***after*** .net.